# Relative primes and Bezout's coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

So I had proved that given $\gcd(a, b) = g$, if $ap + bq = g$, then $\gcd(p, q) = 1$

meaning bezout's coefficients are coprime.

I was then asked to show that if you wrote 
$$a = a'g, \ \ \ \ \ \ b = b'g$$ then $\gcd(a',b') = 1$
I'm not really sure how to go about this.

I currently have written out that $a = a'(gcd(a,b))$ and $b = b'(gcd(a,b))$.
This means that $a'$ is a different factor of $a$ and $b'$ is a different factor of $b$. 
Any idea where I could go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substituting $a = a'g$, $b = b'g$ into $ap + bq = g$ you will get $a'p + b'q = 1$ which is necessary and sufficient condition for $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$, $b$ be two positive integers. If $\gcd(a,b)=g$, then $g$ is the greatest positive integer to divide into both $a$ and $b$. Hence we may write $a=a'g$, $b=b'g$, for $a',\, b'\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$.

Now show that $\gcd(a',b')=1$. To this end assume some $f\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ divides both $a'$ and $b'$. Then it would surely divide $a$ and $b$ and hence divide $g$, since $\gcd(a,b)=g$. Hence you have a contradiction and $f$ cannot exist, and so $\gcd(a',b')=1$.